# Звательный падеж в современном русском

Tags: падежи

Можно увидеть, что, кроме архаических образований *господи* и *боже*, есть и современная форма звательного падежа, а именно звательный в русском получается путём усечения окончания. *Вася-Вась, Катя-Кать и т. д.*

Почему этот падеж редко определяют как самостоятельный? И вообще не упоминают в школьной программе.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова если в моём или другом ответе или вопросе вы найдёте явную орфографическую или пунктуационную ошибку, можете смело её самостоятельно исправить. Если такую ошибку нашли в комментарии, то можете нажать тревога и указать модератору, что нужно исправить.

Comment: Я как-то привыкла соблюдать субординацию и не переоценивать свои сомнительные познания. Каюсь: не обратила внимания на значочек — обратилась бы со своим вопросом напрямую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В чем вопрос?

Почему не упоминают? В школьной программе много чего не упоминают. Я не очень хорошо знаю современный её объем, примеры не буду приводить, но совершенно очевидно, что невозможно вместить туда весь академический курс.

Да, Зализняк, например, определяет усечения кратких имен типа *Саш, Петь, Маш* и некоторых обозначений родственников (пап, тёть) как отдельный падеж.
Он вообще их насчитывает 11(!) штук (помимо "звательного" ещё дополнительно: второй родительный, второй винительный и второй предложный и счётная форма). Ни одну из этих реально существующих форм *Академическая Грамматика* за полноценный падеж не признаёт.

Конкретно, по "новому звательному" главным препятствием является крайне ограниченный список слов, имеющих эту форму, и необязательность употребления именно этой формы против формы именительного.

P.S. Ух ты! Уже 13!!! [Таблица падежей русского языка | nashol.com](http://nashol.com/2011060955536/tablica-padejei-russkogo-ya.zika.html)

*Лишительный* и *ждательный* — это сильно... Я б не додумался...
Кто больше?

Answer (score 4):

В школьной программе упоминают. Говорят, что этот падеж считался седьмым русским падежом в грамматиках, изданных до 1918 года.

Старый звательный падеж (в отличие от так называемого *новозвательного* [Тань, Вась], который является просторечным упрощением именительного падежа) сохранился в словах «Боже», «Господи», «старче», «отче» и других. Форма звательного падежа сохранилась и в словах «деда», «доча» и т. п.
Но название этой формы «падежом» условно, так как в строго грамматическом смысле звательная форма падежом не является. По *форме* звательный  падеж идентичен именительному, но образует независимый оборот речи (обращение), по функциям подобный междометию: выражает чувства, отношение к тому, кого зовём. Следовательно, слово воспринимается не как существительное в каком-то падеже, а как возглас, неизменяемое слово.
Для морфологического разбора обращение не даётся, говорится, что обращение — и всё, морфологические признаки не указываются.

Comment: >>Форма звательного падежа сохранилась и в словах «деда», «доча» и т. п.   
  
Людмила, это никак не (старый) звательный. 
Там флексия -а совершенно невозможна.
По логике должно быть дhде (h-ять) и доче.
Правда там к 1918 г. уже была изрядная путаница, ибо для большиснтва слов звательный совпал с именительным.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, собственно, звательный падеж ушел из современного русского языка. Я бы не стала форму "Вася — Вась" обозначать как звательный падеж. Поэтому, наверное, и не преподают.
Кстати, в украинском он вполне себе жив и употребляется.

Comment: Это *разные* падежи. В случае фозможных разночтений подобная звательная форма обычно сторонниками её "паджности" определяется как *новый* звательный падеж.  
Старый же звательный строго говоря не исчез, просто совпал с именительным.

Answer (score 0):

Генетически звательный падеж есть в русской устной речи, где он четко артикулируется интонационно, но поскольку бал в грамматике правит письменная речь, звательный падеж, там, где он не отличается в написании от именительного, утрачен.

Comment: Что такое "генетически" и как именно артикулируется? Что Вы вообще считаете звательным падежом в современной речи?